# use a custom textgroup from t()

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I've defined my own textgroup using:

```
function foo_locale($op = 'groups') {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'groups':
      return array('foo' => t('foo strings'));
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I use `t('bar')` in a template, the entry generated in the database (e.g when viewing the template in `/fr`) is associated with the `default` textgroup. This doesn't allow me to use the `foo` textgroup I've previously defined, thus all my custom strings are mixed with the other "Built-in interface" ones.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

t('String') *always* belongs to the "Built-in interface". If you have t() texts, then you don't need to create textgroups.

They are meant for strings that are not translated with that function, usually content/configuration. The I18n modules define lots of these groups for things like variables, menus, taxonomy terms and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Since the t() only for UI and you can not select which exactly the grouptext that you prefer. You can use this:

```
$context = $field_name . ':' . $entity_type . ':label';
$label = i18n_string_translate('field:' . $context, $field_info['label']);
```

Example:

```
$context = 'field_custom:article:label';
$label = i18n_string_translate('field:' . $context, 'Custom title');
```

You have to prefix the context with "field:"

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned use i18n module, the specific function is

```
i18n_string_translate($name, $string, $options)
```

This is part of i18n_string module. Here pass $textgroup . $context as $name, the string to be translated as $string. You can also pass $options['langcode'] if translation in a specific language is desired.

Answer (score -1):

You can add strings to a custom text-group by first extracting them to a POT file. Then when you import them at `/admin/config/regional/translate/import` you can assign the strings to your text-group.

Or for user-defined strings you could use the i18n module.

NOTE: Text-groups will be removed in Drupal 8. See http://drupal.org/node/1188430

Comment: This will work, but I do not prefer this way since it will duplicate the phrases and it is not the best solution. Thanks for your help.